# scrape Glassdoor for multiple pages using python lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using the following script to scrape job listings via Glassdoor. The script below only scrapes the first page. I was wondering, how might I extend it so that it scrapes from page 1 up to the last page?

https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-scrape-job-listings-from-glassdoor-using-python-and-lxml/

I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Say the final constructed URL for glassdoor was `https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/boston-android-developer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC1154532_KO7,24.htm?...` then specify the page number as `_IP#.htm` where # is the page number, e.g. `https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/boston-android-developer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC1154532_KO7,24_IP2.htm?...` for page 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a more general answer. When scraping, to get the next page simply get the link on the page to the next page.

In the case of Glassdoor, your page links all have the `page` class and the next page is accessed by clicking an `li` button with class `next`. Your XPath then becomes:

```
//li[@class="next"]
```

You can then access it with:

```
element = document.xpath("//li[@class='next']")
```

We are specifically looking for the link so we can add `a` to our xpath:

```
//li[@class="next"]//a
```

And further specify that we just need the `href` attribute:

```
//li[@class="next"]//a/@href
```

And now you can access the link with

```
link = document.xpath('//li[@class="next"]//a/@href')
```

Tested and working on Glassdoor as of 2/9/18.

Comment: Very nice - how did you implement/test it?